# Is it possible to pipe a file with quotes and special characters to OpenSSL?

Tags: bash, shell, openssl

I am trying to write a bash script that will allow the user to input a password, and then pipe stdin (either via terminal commands or a piped file) to ‘openssl enc’ to encrypt it line by line using that password, and then finally pipe it out to an external TCP server.

This is what I have so far, and it mostly works:

```
#!/bin/bash
printf "What is your encryption 
password?\n"
read -s password </dev/tty
while read line; do echo "$line" | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -base64 -pass pass:$password -e; done > >(openssl s_client -quiet -connect localhost:3001)
```

You run this via cat file | script.sh.

The problem I’m running into is when the file has quotes or special characters in it and breaks the echo.

Is there a way to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `read` and some versions of `echo` will do some kinds of escape/quote/whitespace/etc processing. You can get `read` to behave with `IFS= read -r` -- the `IFS=` prevents it from trimming leading and trailing whitespace (and since it's a prefix, it won't mess other things up like a general assignment to `IFS`), and `-r` tells it not to try to parse escape (backslash) characters. `echo` is hopeless, so use `printf '%s\n'` instead.

You also have similar problems with the `password` variable; use the same `read` tricks, and then expand it in double-quotes to prevent word-splitting and wildcard expansion from doing weird things. Oh, and I prefer to use `read -p prompt` rather than printing a separate prompt, and send a newline to /dev/tty afterward so it doesn't just sit there at the prompt.

The pipe and `openssl` themselves shouldn't be any trouble -- these are both binary-safe interfaces, so no quote or anything parsing there. Mind you, you might have some problems on the decrypt side...

Something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS= read -rs -p "What is your encryption password? " password </dev/tty
echo >/dev/tty
while IFS= read -r line; do
    printf '%s\n' "$line" | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -base64 -pass "pass:$password" -e
done > >(openssl s_client -quiet -connect localhost:3001)
```

Comment: This solution works for me. There was one minor bug that I missed in my original code, so I'll post here for any future readers: the `openssl enc` command also needs the -A flag, otherwise it'll automatically inject a line break in the encoded string every 64 characters.